# How do you pull out the tombstone while running from Dahaka in the tombs?

Tags: prince-of-persia-warrior-within

In *Prince of Persia: Warrior Within*, how do you pull out the tombstone while running from Dahaka in the tombs?

Answer (score 1):

This video seems to cover every chase sequence, but it's been literal years since I last played, so I don't recall the exact part you're talking about.

If it's a moment where you need to get a hidden weapon, I imagine you just need to slow time so you have enough time to remove the tombstone.